# How to transform a data frame with duplicated key for different value to a single key with values as column

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, machine-learning, anaconda

I have a given data shown below

[Given data frame (input)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3c5GL.png)

I want to change this given data to the following data frame

[modifide dataframe (output)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/caaS0.png)

I am using panda from Python library for my work. I am new to panda and python can anyone please help me how to solve this problem using any panda function like pivot `table = pd.pivot_table(table, ......)`or any other python libraries.

Edit :

Sample Data

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'Acc':[1,2,4,2,1,3],'Event':list('ABCACA'),'exit':[0,1,1,1,0,0]})
```

EDIT:

I am` sorry @jpp here is an example for my question:

Let's say this is given input like this

```
`DataFrame({'Acc':[1,2,4,2,1,1,3],'Event':list('ABCACBA'),'exit':[1,1,1,1,0,0,0]})`
```

I am expecting this kind of output

```
# Acc  A  B  C  exit
# 1    1  1  1  1   
# 2    1  1  0  1  
# 4    0  0  1  1  
# 3    1  0  0  0
```

Comment: What you have tried and where is failing? Show us sample of your code :).

Answer (score 0):

IIUC

```
pd.concat([pd.crosstab(df.Acc,df.Event),df.groupby('Acc').exit.last()],1)
Out[37]: 
     A  B  C  exit
Acc               
1    1  0  1     0
2    1  1  0     1
3    1  0  0     0
4    0  0  1     1
```

Data input

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'Acc':[1,2,4,2,1,3],'Event':list('ABCACA'),'exit':[0,1,1,1,0,0]})
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is one solution:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'Acc':[1,2,4,2,1,3],'Event':list('ABCACA'),'exit':[0,1,1,1,0,0]})

df2 = df.groupby(['Acc', 'exit'])['Event'].apply(list).reset_index()
df2 = df2.join(pd.get_dummies(df2['Event'].apply(pd.Series).stack()).sum(level=0))\
         .drop('Event', 1)

#    Acc  exit  A  B  C
# 0    1     0  1  0  1
# 1    2     1  1  1  0
# 2    3     0  1  0  0
# 3    4     1  0  0  1
```

Comment: Thank you @jpp How about if one account has two `0` and one `1` in `exit` column and I want to take `1` only in my `exit` column after data frame join

Comment: @SinshawDemisse, sorry I don't understand. Can you update question with what you want (input / output) ?

Comment: Formatting doesn't work well in comments. You can always update your original question.

Comment: I am` sorry @jpp here is an example for my question:

Let's say this is given input like this
    
    `DataFrame({'Acc':[1,2,4,2,1,1,3],'Event':list('ABCACBA'),'exit':[1,1,1,1,0,0,0]})`

I am expecting this kind of output
    
    `# Acc  exit  A  B  C`
    `# 0    1     1  1  1  1`
    `# 1    2     1  1  1  0`
     `# 2    3     0  1  0  0`
     `# 3    4     1  0  0  1`

Comment: Still can't read the output! You can always update your original question..